# Use Java variables in CSS code

Tags: html, css, jakarta-ee, sass

How to use Java variables in CSS file (for example in Eclipse Java EE projects).

I mean, when we use Java codes ( **<% ... *Java code here* ... %>** ) in HTML codes in JSP file, can we use Java code in CSS file (not in JSP file, in `<style>...</style>` - *not internal insert ([CSS How To...](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp))*).

So, I want to create seperate **style (CSS) file** and JSP file (which imports my **style (CSS) file**).

How can I do this and which is logical and best way?

---

I was using HttpServlet class file and writting there internal CSS code using `PrintWriter.print(...)`, but it is String + String + String + ...

But, there was neccesary use variables for width and height in CSS styling. For example, I had code like this:

**HTML code:**

```
...
myPrintWritter.print
  (
    "<div class=\"outterBox\">\n" +
      "<div class=\"innerBox\">Small Box 1</div>\n" +
      "<div class=\"innerBox\">Small Box 2</div>\n" +
    "</div>\n"
  );
...
```

**CSS code:**

```
int space = 5;
int innerBoxWidth = 50;
int outterBoxWidth = (innerBoxWidth + space + innerBoxWidth);

myPrintWritter.print("<style type=\"text/css\">\n");
...
myPrintWritter.print
  (
    ".outterBox\n" +
    "{\n" +
      "width: " + outterBoxWidth + "px;\n" +
    "}\n" +
    "\n" +
    ".innerBox\n" +
    "{\n" +
      "width: " + innerBoxWidth + "px;\n" +
    "}\n" +
  );
...
myPrintWritter.print("</style>\n");
```

These all codes I had in one HttpServlet class file. Now I want to seperate them (in JSP, CSS,.. files).

I found that I can use CSS variables, more exactly, use SASS and LESS and there possibilities...
Now I can create CSS and SCSS files and write style codes there.

But, it would be better to use only `JAVA and CSS` codes and not `SASS and LESS` and some other...
**

---

Writting a lot of HTML and CSS codes in HttpServlet (or in JSP) using String + String + ... is not problem for me, but its problem for codes typing, highlighting and other... and its also not logical and right way...

1. Can anyone advice me some simple way for my project (problem :D ).
2. Also, if you help me in CSS, could you help me in javascript too (same problem - typing).

---

Thanks everyone...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSS doesn't necessarily have to come from a .css file, any response with an acceptable MIME type can be used. So, not knowing your use case to evaluate whether or not it's a good idea, there's nothing stopping you from using a JSP as a CSS include.

SASS/LESS is probably going to be more of a pain than it's worth here, if you're only using it to bring in these variables, because you'll have to set it up to render on the fly, and you'll have to figure out how to sent the variables for each render in a performant way.

Unless you're adding a lot of CSS this way, printing a CSS block in the HTML like you have is probably the path of least resistance. You can make it a little more readable by only using Java for the variable values, rather than the whole thing, as in `<% myPrintWritter.print(".outterBox { width: "+outterBoxWidth+"px; }" %>` becomes `.outterBox { width: <%=outterBoxWidth;%>px; }`